# Morphia Error : The method fromDBObject(Class<T>, BasicDBObject) in the type Morphia is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Suite>, DBObject)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, morphia

I have written a code which has Suite information with Test case information embedded inside it.I have written the TestCase.java and Suite.java and they seem to have no errors.But with the MongoMapper.java which I have written I am getting this error.
The method fromDBObject(Class, BasicDBObject) in the type Morphia is not applicable for the arguments (Class, DBObject).Kindly help me with this as well as suggest me how to see whether I have my collections updated in the MongoDB Shell.Thanks in advance.Here is my code.

```
package com.DrAssist.Morphia.model;
import com.google.code.morphia.Morphia;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNull;

public class MongoMapper {
    Morphia morph;
    Mongo mongo;
    DBCollection DrAssistReport;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws UnknownHostException {
    morph = new Morphia();
    mongo = new Mongo("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    // This is where we map Persons and addresses
    // But shouldn't the annotation be able to handle that?
    morph.map(Suite.class).map(TestCase.class);
    DB testDb = mongo.getDB( "test" );
    DrAssistReport = testDb.getCollection("DrAssistReport");
    }

    @Test
    public void storePersonThroughMorphiaMapping () {

    Suite suite = new Suite(new TestCase("1",new String[]{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"},"1","5","6","7","889"));
    suite.setSID("1");
    suite.setsuiteName("Suite1");
    suite.setnoOfTests("5");


    DrAssistReport.save(morph.toDBObject(suite));
    Suite suite2 = morph.fromDBObject(Suite.class, DrAssistReport.findOne());
    assertNotNull(suite2.getSID());



    }
}
```

The ERROR I am getting is The method fromDBObject(Class, BasicDBObject) in the type Morphia is not applicable for the arguments (Class, DBObject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a version of Morphia from before this change: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?id=15

You could try either casting the return value from DrAssistReport.findOne() to a "BasicDBObject" or upgrade the verison of Morphia that you're using to a version whose Morphia.fromDBObject method takes a DBObject rather then requiring a BasicDBObject.